# Unable To Assign Variable Within A described Function

Tags: python

Can Someone Pls Tell me How i can assign n to eg. 1 in a def.

PLsssssssss help.

what ever a do with the global the def cant set n = x globally

It is Stuck On n = 0 was astabliched in the very beggining and my onkey commands wont reassign n globally.
 i cant fix it

the global n does not seem to affect my n

n still stuck on 0

my code is now :

```
import turtle
turtle.left(90)
screen = turtle.Screen()
controls = 0
n = 0
screen.listen()
def w0():
  global n
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 0
def w1():
  global n
  turtle.left(90),
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 0
def w2():
  global n
  turtle.right(180)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 0
def w3():
  global n
  turtle.right(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 0
def d0():
  global n
  turtle.right(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 1
def d1():
  global n
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 1
def d2():
  global n
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 1
def d3():
  global n
  turtle.right(180)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 1
def s0():
  global n
  turtle.right(180)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 2
def s1():
  global n
  turtle.right(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 2
def s2():
  global n
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 2
def s3():
  global n
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 2
def a0():
  global n
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 3
def a1():
  global n
  turtle.right(180)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 3
def a2():
  global n
  turtle.right(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 3
def a3():
  global n
  turtle.forward(100)
  n = 3
if n == 0:
  screen.onkey(w0, "w")
  screen.onkey(d0, "d")
  screen.onkey(s0, "s")
  screen.onkey(a0, "a")
  print(n)
if n == 1:
  screen.onkey(w1, "w")
  screen.onkey(d1, "d")
  screen.onkey(s1, "s")
  screen.onkey(a1, "a")
  print(n)
if n == 2:
  screen.onkey(w2, "w")
  screen.onkey(d2, "d")
  screen.onkey(s2, "s")
  screen.onkey(a2, "a")
  print(n)
if n == 3:
  screen.onkey(w3, "w")
  screen.onkey(d3, "d")
  screen.onkey(s3, "s")
  screen.onkey(a3, "a")
  print(n)
```

Comment: global n doesnt work

Comment: `global n` does work, but there are other problems with your code. I can't post a working version, since the question's been closed. You need to call the `onkey()` functions each time `n` changes. One way to do that is to put your `if` statements into a function & call that function at the end of each of your turtle motion functions. And you need a `turtle.mainloop()` at the end of your program (unless you're running it in IDLE or similar).

Comment: THANKS MAN FINALLY FIXED IT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `n` as a global variable... for example:

```
def s3():
    global n
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    n = 2
```

In Python if an assignment is present and a variable is not explicitly declared `global` then it's assumed it's a local variable.